# In CakePHP 2, how do you tell the Paginator component which model to use?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Given the following working example,

```
// ProductsController.php
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator');

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 5
    );

    public function index() {
        $this->Product->recursive = -1;
        $this->set('products', $this->paginate());
    }
}
?>
```

What tells Paginator which model to use when it sets the variable? Currently this seems to be automatically using the Products model, but I don't really understand *why*. Is it just part CakePHP's magic that it selects the model that has the same name as the current controller? And if so, how would I tell Paginator to use some other model? Like if I wanted to also paginate the User model on the same page, how would I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some trial and error, it seems like by default Paginator will just use whatever model is associated with the controller via the naming conventions (the 'User' model is associated with the 'UsersController' controller, and so on).

The first argument of `$this->paginate()` will accept a different model if you want to use one, for example `$this->paginate('Dinglehopper')`, but the specified model needs to be available to the controller/action in order for it to work. In order to do that you need `$this->loadModel('Dinglehopper');` inside the action where `$this->paginate('Dinglehopper')` is called.

So in the hypothetical situation where you want to use and paginate the model 'Dinglehopper' inside your 'Products' controller you would do,

```
// ProductsController.php
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator');

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 5
    );

    public function index() {
        $this->loadModel('Dinglehopper');

        $this->Product->recursive = -1;
        $this->set('dinglehoppers', $this->paginate('Dinglehopper'));
    }
}
?>
```

`$this->loadModel('Dinglehopper');` makes the model 'Dinglehopper' available to the action, and then `$this->paginate('Dinglehopper')` returns the paginated Dinglehopper model.

Answer (score 1):

According to Cakephp2, 
$this->paginate() by default works on the current model.

if you want to use other model on the same page you can do like this:

```
$this->paginate('User');
```

You can all pass other parameters like:

```
  $this->Paginator->settings = array(
         'fields' => array('User.*'),  
         'order'  => array('User.username' => 'asc'),
         'limit'  => 10,
     );
     $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));
```

Reference: [Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)

Comment: I've figured it out now, thanks. I think my main problem was that I wasn't including the model in the action via `$this->loadModel()`.